# Why is stopTimer function not stopping timer?

Tags: angular

I need to stop the timer using stopTimer() function, but it doesn't seem to stop the timer, it just resets it. This is what my TimerService looks like:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class TimerService {
  timePerQuestion = 20;
  elapsedTime = 0;
  timeLeft = new BehaviorSubject<number>(this.timePerQuestion);
  timeLeft$ = this.timeLeft.asObservable();
  completionTimeSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(this.elapsedTime);

  resetTimer(): void {
    this.timeLeft.next(this.timePerQuestion);
  }

  stopTimer(): void {
    this.elapsedTime = Math.ceil(this.timePerQuestion - Number(this.timeLeft$));
    this.timeLeft.next(this.timePerQuestion - this.elapsedTime);
  }

  sendCompletionTimeToResults(value: number): void {
    this.completionTimeSubject.next(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: `this.timeLeft$` refers to an observable. Did you mean to use `this.timeLeft$.value`?

Comment: @pc_coder, I'm looking at your Stackblitz. This might work for me, I think I need to stop the timer in different component though.

Comment: @pc_coder, I am using your code but having couple issues: the timer doesn't seem to reset in between questions and the timer doesn't seem to stop after the correct answer(s) selected. Also the completionTime in ResultsComponent is incorrect. Please could you take a look at my Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-quiz-app. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a simple setTimeout method, call it from constructor or anywhere else:

```
  userActivity;

  constructor() {
    this.setTimeout();
   }

  setTimeout() {
    this.userActivity = setTimeout(() => {
      // Code here when timer runs out
    }, 20000);
  }

  resetInactiveCounter() {
    clearTimeout(this.userActivity);
    this.setTimeout();
  }

  stopTimer() {
    clearTimeout(this.userActivity);
  }
```

Comment: I already have a timer in my TimerComponent. I need the functions to be in TimerService because I am calling them in different places in my program, just for some reason it doesn't seem to stop the timer when I call stopTimer().

Comment: I am using the RxJS version of timer. Thanks for your help.